# find multiple mongoose objects with having common value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to get all objects that have something in common
like i have

```
{
name: 'jhon',
age: 40,
job: 'programmer',
},
{
name: 'rick',
age: 39,
job: 'programmer',
},
{
name: 'casey',
age: 30,
job: 'cooker',
},
```

I want to get all people that has `job = coder` using mongoose

Comment: How it's called your Model? And also there is no coder in your example.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  **$[elemMatch](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#mongodb-query-op.-elemMatch)** for getting job:programmer (i dont see coder here), using mongo query

```
{ results: { $elemMatch: { job: "programmer" } } }
```